# Can not bind viewModel DataGrid with any ways I try

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, .net-framework-version

With any way I try to bind viewModel, DataGrid leaves empty, but binded buttons and textBlocks work very well, I can find items in that and work with that, really don't know how to fix it, help me, please

XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="Workers_managment_entity_framework_practice.workers_viewing_page"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Workers_managment_entity_framework_practice" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="workers_viewing_page">

    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="workersBoard" ItemsSource="{Binding Workers}">
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding LastName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Salary}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding WorkExperience}"></DataGridTextColumn>     
        </DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
public workers_viewing_page()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new WorkersViewModel();
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class WorkersViewModel
    {
        public readonly WorkersService _service;
        public IObservable<WorkerDTO> Workers { get; set; }
```

Edit:
That's way, how I set Workers in ViewModel:

```
   public WorkersViewModel()
    {
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString;
        _service = new WorkersService(connectionString);

        Workers = new ObservableCollection<WorkerDTO>(_service.GetAll());
        
    }
```

Also now I receive error message:
System.InvalidOperationException: "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource."

Comment: Shouldn't your collection type be `ObservableCollection<T>` rather than `IObservable<T>`?

Comment: You need to show us how you set and populate the `Workers` collection.